# setInterval alert does not update with dom attributes

Tags: javascript, html, dom, intervals

When calling an alert for document.body.scrollHeight at 5 second intervals, the alert returns the initial scrollHeight of the document, but does not change even when the scroll height of the page has clearly changed. Is there any way to make it return the actual scroll height of the page, and not just the initial value?

The code/pseudocode

```
<script>
    setInterval(function() {
        alert(document.body.scrollHeight);
    }, 5000);

    function extendHeight() {
    document.getElementById('box').style.height = 1000;
    }
</script>

<body>
  <div id='box' style='height: 500px;'>
    <button onClick="extendHeight();">Change Height</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Even after clicking button, the alert returns 500 px.

Comment: clicking that button looks like an error to me. Post the real code.

Comment: `document.getElementById('box').style.height = '1000px';` ?

Comment: **So the lessons for today:** Units are important and showing the real working example code gives you real answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you should assign `'1000px'` to `document.getElementById('box').style.height` not `1000`:

```
<script>
    setInterval(function() {
        alert(document.body.scrollHeight);
    }, 5000);

    function extendHeight() {
    document.getElementById('box').style.height = "1000px";
    }
</script>

<body>
  <div id='box' style='height: 500px;'>
    <button onClick="extendHeight();">Change Height</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kzLEr/

Comment: I fixed your code above, you had what the OP had and not what was in the fiddle! :)